# How can i fetch custom list columns with javascript?

Tags: javascript, caml

I created a list and it has got GroupName and EmailName columns. I want to fetch the data but this code is not working. How can i solve this?

```
   var GroupName=$(this).attr("GroupName");
```

all the codes part.

```
function processResult(xData, status) { 
$(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row, row").each(function() {
 var title=$(this).attr("ows_Title"); 
 var GroupName=$(this).attr('ows_GroupName'); 
 var STR = "<li><h3>" + title + GroupName +"</h3>" ;

 STR +="</li>"; 


 $("#list").append(STR ); }); }
```

Comment: Hi, Please post your whole code snippet

Comment: hi i added the whole function part. "ows_Groupname" is showing undefined and only "GroupName" is showing undefined too...

Comment: What version of Sharepoint are you using, and what is the REST (or SOAP) call you're using to get your data?  From what you've shown, I'm assuming you're using SOAP or SPServices to execute the query against your list, is that correct?

Comment: I got 2010 version of sharepoint. Yes i am using SOAP services.